# How to route on-premise data gateway traffic through Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: azure, azure-vpn, data-gateway

I have a logic app which requires to access a file which sits on on-prem server. for File System Connector, I have installed on-premise data gateway.
It basically works. But I want to route traffic via Site-to-Site VPN which we have setup between on-prem and Azure

Expected Result: Route on-Premise Data Gateway traffic via Site-to-Site VPN or via Express route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment-overview). *This capability is in public preview*.

> The Integration Service Environment is a deployment of the Logic Apps
>   service into your own virtual network. This enables your logic apps to
>   have direct access to resources over Site-to-site or ExpressRoute
>   connections

[image]

For more references https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment

Comment: yes, I am aware about ISE. is there any other way to achieve above without using ISE?

Comment: I have no idea about other way, since s2s VPN enables network access in a private network, currently logic apps could not access in a virtual network without using ISE.

Comment: what about express route ?  anyway what is the best way (bandwidth wise) to read on-prem file from azure logic app?

Comment: Traditional VPN connection sets up a tunnel over the Internet, whereas, the [express route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-introduction) itself is over a private connection facilitated by a connectivity provider. Configuring a secure tunnel over ExpressRoute allows for data exchange with confidentiality, anti-replay, authenticity, and integrity. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/site-to-site-vpn-over-microsoft-peering). The express route is more secure and fast and high cost.